# Any good lightbox for a modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

There are thousands of lightbox components and the likes.
I've looked at about 10 of them, but couldn't find what I need.

Just wondering if anyone know a lightbox like component that:

- can popup an inline div (that is initially hidden)
- can be modal (eg. you must select a radio button or you can't close the box)
- can be called dynamically, eg. so that I can call `Popup('myDiv');` on page load without the user clicking anything
- has sufficient documentation/examples to allow me do the above easily

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) is a very nice jQuery plugin for making modal popups.

*Popup an inline hidden div* (I do this all the time with it):

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#divID') });
```

*Can be modal*: it won't close the popup until you call `$.unblockUI()`

*Dynamic*: Just call $.blockUI() where ever you wish, including page load

*Documentation*: LOTS of examples on their site

Comment: Thank you Bryan this is very good it has clear examples.
(Thanks too everyone who has suggested other things)

Answer (score 0):

I think [Facebox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox) will give you everything except preventing the user from "closing" it.

Otherwise there's always jQuery UI's Dialog widget, [which does have that feature](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Fancybox ([http://fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net/)/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/), which meets all of those requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html), specifically [Overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/index.html).